XCFramework include additional public headers with xcodebuild
I do have a fairly large obj-c static library I have converted to XCFramework and for the base that works great. Thing is, the old library compiled differently based on xcodebuild defines and created like 20 different variants, containing more header files, something like:
base:
Headers

mainheader.h

variant1:
Headers

mainheader.h
customheader.h

..
However I failed to find a way from the commandline with xcodebuild to mark specific headers to be public to copy when creating the framework. I can make that magic with adding more targets, sure, but prefer to not go that route unless I have to
